# appendChild before the node is completed loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

Can I appendChild a `<script>` element in the HEAD before the HEAD itself is completly loaded?

Example:

```
<head>
<script src="my.js">
//etc
```

in the `my.js` there is:

```
var thescript = document.createElement('script');
thescript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
thescript.setAttribute('src','otherfile.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(thescript);
```

this code will be executed before browsers reach `</head>`

is this safe or could cause problmes?
I want to do this because I want load jquery from my .js script so i don't have to edit my pages to add the other `<script>` manually

Many Thanks

Comment: I don't think the head element will be available until it finishes loading...

Comment: You could just add the script into the body?

Comment: It's generally not safe to do DOM modification at this point in the page load, but a document.writeln('<script language="javascript" src="otherfile.js" />'); should be fine.

Comment: @lazy: you are a genius thanks you so much. Also remeber to split the script string otherwise chrome makes errors (`scr'+'ipt`), Also make a reply i will pick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not safe to do DOM modification at this point in the page load, but a document.writeln('<script language="javascript" src="otherfile.js" />'); should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much what the Google Analytics Asynchronous tracking code does and it doesn't usually encounter problems. Using a similar technique to GA it could look as follows:

```
(function() {
   var thescript = document.createElement('script');
   thescript.type = 'text/javascript';
   thescript.src = 'otherfile.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(thescript, s);
})();
```

However, remember that the code inside 'otherfile.js' might not be available straight away so you need to take that into consideration. GA uses a queue that you can add function calls to that will execute once the script is available.

Answer (score 0):

The head element will not be available before it is fully loaded.  You can use a different approach, though:

Include only one file, called "includes.js".  It should look like this:

```
function include_once(src) {
  // get script elements already in the HTML source code,
  // abort if script has been loaded
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  if ( scripts ) {
    for ( var k=0; k < scripts.length; k++) {
      if ( scripts[k].src == src ) return; 
    }
  }
  // include if not already loaded
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.body).appendChild(script);
}

// add all your scripts here
function addIncludes () {
    include_once ( 'js/my.js' );
}
```

Then, call addIncludes onload:

```
<body onload="addIncludes()">
```

(This example was taken and modified from a [german site](http://www.naden.de/blog/javascript-include-once).)

If you have JS that has to be executed directly after loading, you need to set an interval and test for availability of the additional .js files - remember they are loaded *after* the original page is complete.